# Aggregate a dataframe and count for each category

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
time             city             
2018-05-8        sydney        
2018-05-8        sydney
2018-05-8        melbourne
2018-05-9        sydney
2018-05-9        melbourne
```

I am trying to get the following:

```
time             syndey_count  melbourne_count 
2018-05-8        2             1
2018-05-9        1             1
```

So far I've managed to group by the time then aggregate by the city:

```
df.groupby('time').agg({'city': 'count'})
```

but that just gives me:

```
time             city  
2018-05-8        3             
2018-05-9        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.time,df.city)
Out[77]: 
city       melbourne  sydney
time                        
2018-05-8          1       2
2018-05-9          1       1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
In [53]: df.groupby('time').city.value_counts().unstack(level=1).add_suffix('_count')
    ...: 
Out[53]: 
city       melbourne_count  sydney_count
time                                    
2018-05-8                1             2
2018-05-9                1             1
```

Comment: Great answer! Just one thing, what does unstack do?

Comment: @timothyylim Pivot a level of index to the column side. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```
df.groupby(['time', 'city']).size().unstack().add_suffix('_count')
```